# Angularjs update model partially in input value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-model

i've a strange behaviour with a model.

```
$scope.ev = temp;

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDataFineEv" ng-model="ev.dataOraFineEvento" placeholder="Data fine" value="{{ev.dataOraFineEvento | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}">
```

The result in html source is:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" id="inputDataFineEv" ng-model="ev.dataOraFineEvento" placeholder="Data fine" value="12/09/2015">
```

and on screen i see timestamp

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbSYk.jpg)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What is `temp`? Or what is `dataOraFineEvento`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can't use the `value` attribute with an `ng-model` because it's `ng-model` to do the bind, so you should filter the date from the controller to directly bind it filtered:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDataFineEv" ng-model="ev.dataOraFineEvento" placeholder="Data fine">
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'])
    .controller('dummy', ['$scope', '$filter', function ($scope, $filter) {

    $scope.ev = {
        dataOraFineEvento: $filter('date')((1441113680*1000), 'mm/dd/yyyy')
    };

}]);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/f3n1v3ap/)